# iOS - UISearchBar width changes in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uisearchbar

I have been using **UISearchbar** in my project with no problem at all in iOS7 now when i build my project using Xcode 6.0.1 and run on iOS8 the width of UISearchBar automatically changes for example

- If my app is in landscape mode (iPad) and the search bar was in center and had 200 points then this width changes to full 1024 automatically.

I am not using **auto layout**, when i enable **auto layout** the issue is solved but whatever i do to change the frame in code nothing happens.

I don't want to enable autoLayout, how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by using following code

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    searchbar.frame = CGRectMake(365, 0, 274, 44);
}
```

Hope this help someone